# Is there a MILS-like standard for medieval villages and castles?

Tags: design, afol

I'm aware of the [MILS standard](http://www.abellon.net/MILS/) for building large layouts including city and train elements:

[image: MILS example]

This could obviously be adapted for use in medieval layouts, but is there something like this that has already been standardized and put in use by LUGs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Modular Medieval Village Standard](https://rochlug.org/cms/?p=1461) put together by the Rochester, NY LUG (RochLUG) provides this. It features an underlying support layer very similar to MILS:

[image: support layer]

Most modules will feature a randomized cobblestone road providing transit between structures:

[image: Outside corner element]

Structures of various kinds can be added to the modules:

[image: Structure example]

Many modules created by different people can be connected to create convincing medieval villages:

[image: complete village]

Complete details of the system can be found in the [PDF shared by RochLUG](https://rochlug.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/RochLUG-Medieval-Village-Standard.pdf).

Comment: I think this is simply a variation of MILS as explained [here](http://www.abellon.net/MILS/). And it is something that usually agreed between several exposition members to have a matching layout. [Moduverse](https://www.swebrick.se/index.php?topic=6350.0) would be a kind of different approach.

Comment: @Alex It is very similar to MILS. There are fewer Technic pin locations, and it opts for roads on the edges of modules instead of the center as is typical for MILS. Jetro described it as "almost MILS compatible " on LAN. But you are correct, it is essentially an adaptation of MILS specifically for use in medieval villages.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit stubborn. To be honest I find both the question and answer quite odd. 1) There is no real problem or question here. 2) What you have encountered here is a need of a custom module (adopting existing MILS standard). There are tons of other custom MILS/MILS-like modules created. 3) Are we OK now with posting instructions to own modules here as answers? 4) RochLUG article has been posted just yesterday and I find it odd that the question has been a real issue. It looks more like promotion to me.

Comment: @Alex No problem at all. I appreciate this feedback. 1) This is about knowledge sharing, not about a "real" problem that I am currently facing. 2) Correct. I find this useful as it has been created and used by a LUG and worked well. It should be helpful for LUGs that haven't done this before. 3) Additional answers are welcome. I am looking for standards that have been successfully used by LUGs, not untested designs, though. 4) I'm not affiliated with RochLUG. My hope is that this answer helps to surface freely-available content that I believe helps address a need in the LEGO community.

Comment: just putting in my 2 cents as the creator of this template... I have zero experience with MILS, but created this specifically for our LUG to have an easy modular village setup. The road on the edges is far superior for this project... it allows you to place a building and road all on a single 32x32 baseplate. Road through the center would make it very difficult to space building correctly without adding a lot more sections. Simple is sometimes better when it comes to getting people of varying skill and commitment together on a group project. Thanks for sharing the template!

Comment: @JeffJohnson That makes sense. Thanks for putting this together and making it available to others!

Comment: Also, despite the article being written a couple of days ago on our website, we have been using this template for over 3 years now. Someone on the LAN asked if the template was hosted anywhere to share with others, so that's what prompted the article.